# Android: Updating sharedPreferences Summary via listener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, summary

I am having a few issues with updating the summary line in the SharedPreferences as a preference changes.  I have a registered OnSharePreferenceChangeListener in the onResume(), and an unregister of the same in the onPause().

The listener is functioning, and I am able to use the onSharedPreferenceChanges() method.  The issue I am having is being able to retrieve the preference there so that I can call setSummary().  I am in Ice Cream Sandwich, and it appears as though the findPreference(key) method is deprecated. So:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
Preference pref = findPreference(key);}
```

is not functioning, and actually returns null for pref.  From the examples I have seen, you need to get a preference to call setSummary() on it, and ideas?

Comment: `findPreference` is not deprecated, but rather you shouldn't be using a `PreferenceActivity` (that is deprecated). If you only need to support Android 3.0+ then you should switch to `PreferenceFragment`'s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use an `onSharedPreferenceChangedListener` for this.

Instead, use something similar to this.

```
ListPreference myPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("preference_key");
myPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (((String)newValue).equals("some_value")) {
            preference.setSummary("my summary");
        }
    }
});
```

`findPreference` is not deprecated, but rather you shouldn't be using a `PreferenceActivity` (that is deprecated). If you only need to support Android 3.0+ then you should switch to `PreferenceFragment`'s, the new method. If you need to support Android 2.1+ then it is fine and you can ignore the warnings.

Comment: I see.  A few questions though:

Comment: This would require me to set a listener for each preference correct?  I have many preferences across the program, which is why I was using sharedPreferences.

Also, I think that findPreference("Preference_key") you are using is the deprecated one.  ;)

Comment: `((String)newValue)` - this casting is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to use `PreferenceFragment` in my code, and I was also seeing `findPreference(key)` return `null`. The sample code on the [Settings documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) for using `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` hasn't been fully updated for `PreferenceFragment` and you'll crash with `NullPointerException` if you use it verbatim.

I finally figured it out: You have to find the `Preference` via the `PreferenceFragment` because of course that's where the preferences are now. Obvious in hindsight. Something like this:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{   
    protected SettingsFragment settingsFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment).commit();
    }

    // ...

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("your_key")) {
            String newValue = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
            settingsFragment.findPreference(key).setSummary(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bjnord, this is exactly the problem that I have, and I believe that your answer is the rigth way, but to enable that listener, sample code tells to register in onResume() and onPause() with getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()         .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);  but this code crash because this last method give me NullPointerException. Are you  using other way to enable the listener?? Thanks

Comment: Gives me NullPointerException only for Android 3.0+, for Api<11 it runs fine, as findpreference().