# Updating dynamicaly summary preference with fragment?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I've got a problem with updating the summary value of a PreferncesFragment. I have tried to follow the advice of the post : [Updating sharedPreferences Summary via listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639456/android-updating-sharedpreferences-summary-via-listener) but it doesn't work ! The summary doesn't update...

I don't understand what is wrong ? Thank's for your help !

My pref file :

> ```
>     <CheckBoxPreference 
>         android:key="is_title"
>         android:summary="@string/conf_istitle_sum"
>         android:title="@string/conf_istitle_title" 
>         android:defaultValue="true"
>     />
> ```

```
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="sms_title"
        android:title="@string/conf_sms_title" 
        android:summary="@string/msgtitre"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/conf_diagsms_title"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/conf_diagsms_sum"    
        android:defaultValue="@string/msgtitre"
        />
```

My Preference class :

> public class SetPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity  implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
>    {
>          protected MyPreferenceFragment settingsFragment;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   settingsFragment = new MyPreferenceFragment();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                settingsFragment).commit();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        if (key.equals("sms_title")) {
            String newValue = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
            settingsFragment.findPreference(key).setSummary(newValue);
        }
    }
    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


           }

          }
}
```

What's working is the "old" solution deprecated [OldPreferences](https://andrologiciels.wordpress.com/astuces-android/divers-2/preferences/ecran-de-gestion-des-preferences/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is being called at all. You need to register the handler with your preferences. First, 
get a reference to your preferences in `onCreate`:

```
public class SettingsActivity 
    extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        // ...
}
```

In the lifecycle of the Activity (note that I am using a plain `AppCompatActivity`rather than a `PreferenceActiviy`) register the handeler.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    preferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

Now, the handler should be called:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, key);
    // fragment.findPreference(key) //... TBD
}
```

Comment: Registering the handler fixes my problem, thank you so much!